# display number on top or bottom of a candlestick chart with plotly or other charting libraries

Tags: python, plotly

Assume my data look like this:

[image]

With open/close/high/low/ I want to display a normal candlestick, but I also want to add the number in annotation column to top or bottom of the candlestick chart (like chart below), can anyone help me potentially ways how to achieve it. Thank you!

[image]

I have tried mplfinance, but looking is not that great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to annotate, but in the case of this question it is easiest to use the text mode for scatter plots. After creating the candlestick, add a scatter plot. To link the position to be annotated in the string to the candlestick, the opening and closing prices are compared, with the price corresponding to the annotation position as the value. In addition, since all text annotation positions are set to "top center," an offset position is set and calculated. This could be done by having a list of annotation positions for every line. However, since there is no clear rule regarding the annotation position, we have set it to the candlestick reference.

```
offset = 0.004
df['txt_position'] = np.where(df['Open'] >= df['Close'], df['Open'], df['Low'] - offset)

import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Candlestick(
        x=df['Date'],
        open=df['Open'],
        high=df['High'],
        low=df['Low'],
        close=df['Close'],
        name='candlestick'
    )
)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],
                         y=df['txt_position'],
                         mode='text',
                         text=df['Annotation'],
                         textposition='top center',
                         name='annotation')
             )

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: LOVE you for answer my first ever stackoverflow question! Felt so encouraged, totally solved the problem. 

I have many stocks in one dataframe like the data input above, my end goal is to create a simple tool could be just in jupyternotebook or a web based to play the candlestick chart one by one, something like  a plotly candlestick chart with 2 buttons:  < Last Ticker  > Next Ticker button, what is the best tool to achieve that, is it Dash? can you help point me the right direction so I can start learning more.

Comment: My advice would be to master the plotly button function first, then move on to Dash, which is less of a learning curve, see [here](https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/#update-button) for pltoly buttons.

Comment: And may I ask a follow up if I want to add arrow marker when the annotation text is = 10 for example, what's the best way to do it? thank you so much!

Comment: If you want to add arrows, you must use the special annotation function. See [here](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#text-annotations) for more information.